# ScrollView and Groups using Corona SDK

Tags: scrollview, coronasdk

I am using Corona SDK and I need to use ScrollView to display some information that I am pulling from a SQLite database.  I would like to know if I need to have the data that is displayed in a group to be able to use scroll view.  If I do, could you please provide some sample code that I could use to insert the data into the ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the data like image name, path, etc from a DB, then you can simply add them to the scroll view. Otherwise, it depends. I am giving you the code for creating a simple scroll view in corona SDK:

```
-- Require 'widget'
local widget = require( "widget" )

--Creating scroll view
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
                {
                    top = 100,
                    left = 0,
                    width = 320,
                    height = 470,
                    scrollWidth = 320,
                    scrollHeight = 800,
                    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
                    backgroundColor = {255,255,255,200}  -- r,g,b, alpha
                }

-- Let the following be the image path from DB
local filePathFrom_DB = "assets/image_1.png"

-- Create a image using the fetched path
local background = display.newImageRect( filePathFrom_DB, 100, 100 )
background.x = 160

--Insert the image object into the scroll view
scrollView:insert( background )
```

For more details, visit : [Corona API - widget.newScrollView()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html#backgroundcolor-optional)

Keep Coding................. :)